# Add up Figures in Different Files for same Customer Named

Tags: java, file, io

I have a requirement where I have Multiple Customer Invoices as different files. I am able to read the Customer Name and the Invoice Amount from each Invoice. The requirement is that for one customer, I should add up all the invoice amounts.

Here Is My Code:

```
String[] filenames1 = laf.splitFileNames();
FileInputStream fs;
BufferedReader br;
String line;
for (String filename1 : filenames1) {
    fs = new FileInputStream(outFolder + filename1);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
    for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++) {
        br.readLine();
    }
    line = br.readLine().trim();
    String cust_name = line.substring(12);//Returns the Customer Name
    String amount = rll.lastNonBlankLine(new File(outFolder + filename1));//Returns Invoice Amount in String format
    System.out.println(cust_name + "-" + rll.lastNonBlankLine(new File(outFolder + filename1)));
}
```

My Out put:

```
TAITA TAVETA TEACHERS SACCO-25,101.53
TAITA TAVETA TEACHERS SACCO-12,927.62
TAITA TAVETA TEACHERS SACCO-12,927.62
NOT FOR CUSTOMER-12,927.62
```

Ideally I should be able to get:

```
TAITA TAVETA TEACHERS SACCO-50,956.77
NOT FOR CUSTOMER-12,927.62
```

Please assists at this point where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to somehow parse the amount string into some number type, probably BigDecimal. Then you could keep a Map from customer names to the current sum, which you continually update, while you read values.
Only when you are done reading in the files, you would then output the accumulated sums.

So you next steps should be:

- Look up the reference documentation for BigDecimal, looking for a  way to parse them.
- Look up the reference documentation of Map, figuring out how they work and how that would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think if this really help bu i should say, that your problem maybe when Returns Invoice Amount in String format, you do:

```
String amount = rll.lastNonBlankLine(new File(outFolder + filename1));
```

but when you print it, you will get another Invoice amount:

```
System.out.println(cust_name + "-" + rll.lastNonBlankLine(new File(outFolder + filename1)));
```

I think You have to do something like:

```
System.out.println(cust_name + "-" + amount);
```

Comment: It is the same Salah in any case the out printing is Just for debugging. I need the Figures for further Processing.